# Yaru Dark disappeared with this morning's update

Tags: themes, 18.10

Why? This was a fantastic and modern theme that wasn't too bright and was easy on the eyes.

Comment: A few more details would help a lot: Have you tried simply re-enabling it, or is that not possible? If it was, say, missing from the theme settings, have you tried reinstalling it? What else have you tried?

Comment: @wjandrea I tried to reselect via Tweaks. I've tried to reinstall. Not sure what I could try.

Comment: OK, what was the outcome? If there were any error messages, please add them to the question.

Comment: @wjandrea there are no error messages. It would seem it's been removed due to the fact that it's incomplete.

Comment: Which options are available to you in the Tweaks' theme section? If there is more than one, what happens when you select any of them?

Comment: @zurdo there's only one option for Yaru. The other got removed.