# Yaru Gnome shell theme not showing up?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, 18.10

Upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10.

The GTK theme and icons are working except the Gnome shell theme. It lists the package as installed but it doesn't show up in Gnome Tweaks.

```
$ apt-cache policy yaru-theme-gnome-shell
yaru-theme-gnome-shell:
  Installed: 18.10.6
  Candidate: 18.10.6
  Version table:
 *** 18.10.6 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

[image]

I tried these commands but the problem persists:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-session
sudo apt-get --reinstall install yaru-*
```

Comment: It's the default theme. /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/yaru/gnome-shell. css

Comment: That's Adwaita for me.

Comment: I'm saying Default isn't Yaru for me it's Adwaita. There's no gnome-shell.css in /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru either. Edit: Sorry I'm blind it is there.

Comment: that theme will be shown as "Default" in Gnome Tweaks under Shell Themes tab..

Comment: Another yaru puzzle here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086339/yaru-dark-disappeared-with-this-mornings-update

Comment: @PRATAP "Default" isn't Yaru. This is Gnome's default theme. https://imgur.com/a/FrhLHlO

Comment: @Ubuntuthrow yes.. You are rite. I installed 18.10 as a fresh and I only have that default theme. No other themes pre installed. Is your question solved or not yet?

Comment: I have not installed any other shell themes.. And when I change anything in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css` file, it gets reflected thus I confirm this is the default theme which is in Yaru folder.

Comment: Nope still can't use Yaru gnome shell theme.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-session
sudo apt-get --reinstall install yaru-*
```

worked for me, but I had to restart to finally see Yaru listed in the tweaks tool.

Here is the reported [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1798984) to track the 'official' solution:

Answer (score 0):

Since you upgraded from 18.04: do you have a specific session for the new theme on the login window? I installed the communitheme, and that's how that works on 18.04. You need to log in using a session using the new theme.

Comment: It gets installed with 18.10 and it's like a normal theme. There is no session specific to it.