# Upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 - Now things look wrong

Tags: gnome, upgrade, icons, themes

I've upgraded to Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. (`sudo do-release-upgrade` after regular `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`)

Several things in the appearance now seem off. The terminal previously had a maroon background colour, now it's plain white. The terminal scroll bar on the right is badly positioned. See screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oyW1.jpg).

The icons used don't appear as expected. I'm expecting something like [this](https://www.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ubuntu-20.04-lts-scaled.jpg). Instead I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCJXc.jpg). Look at the icons on the left [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1dy.jpg).

The Language Support icon also appears as a white silhouette.

Changing theme variant under Settings > Appearance to "dark" has no effect.

Something in gnome needs resetting?

More info:

I just installed Gnome Tweaks, "Applications" was originally set to Adwaita. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbzFa.jpg). Screenshot doesn't enable capture of picklist options, but the options are Adwaita (default), Ambience, HighContract, HighContrastInverse, Radience. The icons seem to be messed up; For example, there's no difference between HiColor, DMZ-White, DMZ-Black.

Options for Icons are Adwaita (default), DMZ-Black, DMZ-White, Gnome, HiColor, HighContrast, Humanity, Humanity-Dark, LoginIcons, Ubuntu-mono-dark, Ubuntu-mono-light.

The default "Yaru" theme for 20.04 is not listed, but is present under /usr/share/themes/

Resetting to defaults causes all Appearance "Themes" options to go blank.

XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
ubuntu
```

Comment: Was it Ubuntu? It looks more like Xubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 How so? It pretty much looks like Ubuntu (with GNOME 3) with the Adwaita theme to me.

Comment: What icon and application themes do you currently have? Check in GNOME Tweaks. Can you change those to any other that fixes the issue for you? Also what is the output of the following command in Terminal: `echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP`. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Question updated with more info.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087360/45991):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-session
sudo apt-get --reinstall install yaru-*
```